# Deploy multiple project solution to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first

I have solution that consist of several project (frontend - MVC, access layer - codefirst and business layer).

What should I do to deploy these project to single azure web apps ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can deploy multiple projects in single Azure web app using Application Settings -> virtual applications and directories to set multiple project locations and marking them as application.

[image]

Check this blog - This explains the steps 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx

Comment: Thank Gandhali,
but the virtual directories will create kind of myroot/mydirectories kind of arrangement right ?

Do I still able to run my code first entity framework in that way ?

Comment: Should not be an issue. Check this complete tutorial. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks a lot.